# What is needed for this site to get out of beta?

Tags: discussion

The title pretty much sums it up. Do we have to score an "Excellent" in every aspect listed on the [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry) over a certain period of time or what are the requirements for getting out of beta status?

Comment: While not an official answer from the team, this answer encompasses the current philosophy http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215606/159165.  From my own observations, attaining an excellent rating is neither sufficient nor necessary for graduation.

Comment: @jonsca Thank you very much for the link. The philosophy on site graduation laid out there sounds good. Now, I just have to convince my gut that we are ready :)

Comment: I think we could use some more backup on the unanswered questions front. I also think, that there could be some more voting on many questions. However small the community might be at that moment, it is quite healthy and progression might just be a question of time.

Comment: Is there a downside to being in beta?

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding on Area 51 with the number of answers posted per question for Chemistry.SE. Most questions are answered by people with knowledge of the subject, so a reasonably correct answer is given. People rarely provide a guess as an answer (although they might post a comment). This is not like computer science where there is a multitude of ways to program a task.

Comment: @LDC3 I agree and would like to add that on tex.sx it is quite common to have only one answer to a question. I understand that in academia.se there are multiple (so many) answers to every question. Even if there are sometimes charms hidden in the low ranked answers, almost always the accepted one already appears to be too much for my brains to comprehend.

Comment: @LDC3 To add along with what you are saying, chemistry is a topic which can require a lot of effort to type an answer to a seemingly easy question.  Many times you have to decide 'how far down the rabbit hole' you want to go.  While experienced chemists can use models to explain things to each other (because we know 'what you mean by it' so we don't have to explicitly write everything out...), it may be dangerous to do so with the inexperienced as they may automatically assume that the given answer is Gospel.

Comment: The exact thresholds on A51 are meaningless, they were set years ago and never updated. I don't think any of the A51 stats are a problem, my own suspicion is that there is not enough growth in traffic at this point (not the absolute number is important here, but the trend).